# How can I make the cache name in Spring cache configurable?

Tags: java, spring, caching, dependency-injection

We use Spring cache framework for caching, and we'd like to able to support multiple namespaces for caches, such as "book", or "isbn", with the cache namespaces being configurable, rather than hardcoded in the class, like, instead of having

```
@Cacheable({ "book","isbn"})
public Book findBook(ISBN isbn) {...}
```

we want to be able somehow inject the cache name from a properties file, so that the cache name can be dynamically set, like:

```
@Cacheable({ #cachename1, #cachename2})
public Book findBook(ISBN isbn) {...}
```

I'm using SpEL here, but don't know if this is doable at all.

Answer (score 11):

Going off [smartwjw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2576076/smartwjw)'s answer...

I was looking to have cacheNames resolved via spring environment variables, such as `@Cacheable("${my.config.property.name}")`. I accomplished this via a custom `CacheResolver`

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheOperationInvocationContext;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.SimpleCacheResolver;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertyResolver;

public class PropertyResolvingCacheResolver
    extends SimpleCacheResolver {

    private final PropertyResolver propertyResolver;

    protected PropertyResolvingCacheResolver(CacheManager cacheManager, PropertyResolver propertyResolver) {
        super(cacheManager);
        this.propertyResolver = propertyResolver;
    }

    @Override
    protected Collection<String> getCacheNames(CacheOperationInvocationContext<?> context) {
        Collection<String> unresolvedCacheNames = super.getCacheNames(context);
        return unresolvedCacheNames.stream()
            .map(unresolvedCacheName -> propertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(unresolvedCacheName)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

And then of course you must configure it as THE `CacheResolver` to use with a `@Configuration` that extends `org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachingConfigurerSupport`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

    public static final String PROPERTY_RESOLVING_CACHE_RESOLVER_BEAN_NAME = "propertyResolvingCacheResolver";

    @Autowired
    private CacheManager cacheManager;
    @Autowired
    private Environment springEnv;

    @Bean(PROPERTY_RESOLVING_CACHE_RESOLVER_BEAN_NAME)
    @Override
    public CacheResolver cacheResolver() {
        return new PropertyResolvingCacheResolver(cacheManager, springEnv);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Spring 4.1 introduces `CacheResolver`, and use your self defined `CacheResolver` to select `Cache` then can be dynamic. [spring 4.1 cache impovements](https://spring.io/blog/2014/06/16/further-cache-improvements-in-spring-4-1)

Answer (score 1):

you can also use the cache directly, makes all even more predictable

```
EhCacheCacheManager cacheManager = (EhCacheCacheManager) CDBBeanFactory.instance().getBean("cacheManager");
CacheManager manager cacheManager.getCacheManager();
manager.getCache("cacheBin").get("key");
manager.getCache("cacheBin").put(new Element(key, obj));
```

etc ..

Answer (score 0):

Nope, dynamic (SpEL or otherwise) expressions are not supported for the cache name (`value`) property of the @Cacheable annotation. You would have to implement your own version of the `org.springframework.cache.annotation.SpringCacheAnnotationParser` and get it injected into the framework.

Comment: thanks, where can I find some docs or examples on how to imlement SpringCacheAnnotationParser?

Comment: I think you're going to have to dig down into the actual code and figure it out. This is not really a documented "feature" but rather a modification/extension of core functionality.